# I am unable to install java8 on my ubuntu gcp machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, apt

I have tried with the commands

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

but after I could see that Java was not installed on my ubuntu machine. It hits the error like `unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer`

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
reading package lists...done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
E:Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Oracle java 8 is no longer available from there. Either switch to openjdk or download it directly from oracle's website.

Answer (score 2):

That PPA has been [discontinued](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) by its author because of changes in Oracle's legal terms for Java downloads.

Now to download the Oracle JDK you have to go through the [Oracle Download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or use the OpenJDK builds (e.g. the ones provided by your distribution or the ones from [AdoptOpenJKD](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)).